# respond to key press javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm sorry if this is basic, but I've searched and found nothing that works.

I want to load a web page.  When that page loads, it displays an image.  I want to have the page automatically start listening for a right arrow key press.  When that happens, a function in my script will change the image (that part I have gotten to work by using a button that reacts when clicked).

It's the listening for and reacting to a key press I cannot get to work.  Note that I'm using Safari, but I would like if possible for it to work in firefox or IE as well.

Please help thanks.

UPDATE TO RESPOND TO COMMENT:  Here is what I tried, though I simplified the other part to make this shorter -- now it just writes a result to a div:

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="Javascript">
function reactKey(evt) {
   if(evt.keyCode==40) {
      document.getElementById('output').innerHTML='it worked';
   }
}
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="document.onkeypress = reactKey();">
<div id="output"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 3):

If  you are using jquery, you can do this:

```
$(document).keydown(function(e){
    if (e.keyCode == 39) { 
       alert( "right arrow pressed" );
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I am not using jquery - is there no way to do this without it?

Comment: @thf yes but it can be complex to program against browser compatibility.

Answer (score 3):

```
document.onkeydown= function(key){ reactKey(key); }

function reactKey(evt) {
   if(evt.keyCode== 40) {
      alert('worked');
   }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dY9bT/1/

Comment: tried it, but nothing happened.  Note that I did this: `<body onload="document.onkeypress=function(key){ reactKey(key); }">`

Comment: I see. I updated my answer with the correct code. It seems that it only works with onkeydown. You can probably put this in the body onload, though I didn't try. Here is the fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/dY9bT/1/

Comment: There is no need for 2 functions. You can just do `document.onkeydown=reactKey`. Why use magic number 40? I had to go look up key codes to find out which key it was. I wanted to edit the answer to get rid of unnecessary anonymous function and a magic number but it says that edit queue is full.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest thing to do is use one of the many many many hotkey libraries, like https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys or https://github.com/marquete/kibo.

EDIT: try something like this (after you've already loaded Kibo's javascript).

In your body statement, add the `onload` handler: `<body onload="setuphandler">`.

Then add something like this (taken from the Kibo page):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var k = new Kibo();
function setuphandler()
{
  k.down(['up', 'down'], function() {
  alert("Keypress");
  console.log('up or down arrow key pressed');
});
}
</script>
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I guess I'm one step behind.  Kibo says to include the source -- done.  Then it says this:  "Then set up an event listener by creating an instance of Kibo: var k = new Kibo();"  Where do I add that last part -- in <body onload="...">?  That's the part that's throwing me.

Comment: I tried the edit.  Nothing happens. I hit up and down and the web page goes down and (if it has already scrolled down) up.

Comment: You looked at the console and saw nothing?

Comment: No, it's not the easiest. It's easier to write `document.onkeydown= onKeyDown; function onKeyDown(evt){letkeyA=65; if(evt.keyCode==keyA){alert('worked');}}` than to download a whole library.