# How do i make a function to switch between two models when a keyboard button is pressed?

Tags: javascript

I'm wanting to make a function to display two models and switch between the two when a button on the keyboard is pressed.

I've got one of the model's into the website but want to be able to switch between the two, any help will be greately appreciated.

The code for the first model can be seen below.

```
var loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
        loader.load('blood.DAE', function (collada) {

            object = collada.scene;
            object.position.x = 0;
            object.position.y = 0;
            object.position.z = 0;
            object.updateMatrix();
            scene.add(object);
            }
            );
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7600916/2535335

Comment: Possible duplicate of [keydown on body?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2226346/keydown-on-body)